# Windows can view directories but not ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, filesystem, hibernate

Ok. I know i messed up by hibernating one OS and working in other. As i remember i hibernated the Ubuntu. Now a lot of directories are not showing up in ubuntu. But shows up & works in Windows. Directories that were shown fine on Ubuntu before. Drive is NTFS.

If i create new files from Ubuntu, Windows can see & execute them. But if i create something from Windows, It does not show up on Ubuntu. I've faced this problem in the past and somehow i managed to repair this. But i can't remember the method now.

Please help me. Everyone on the internet have the opposite problem. Ubuntu things are not showing in Windows. But here it's the opposite. It's not affordable to format the drive with all the data i have in there.

Comment: Have you tried logging in to then shutting down both systems, removing the hibernation data?

Comment: @Dr.Doctor yeah i tried but no luck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to no one i found the solution on my own. I was just hopeless and when i was messing around in Windows, i just ran a **`chkdsk /f`** on the drive with the issue. It fixed some indexes in few files & when i get to Ubuntu, BAM!! Everything's there.

My advice is; in a case like this, **Don't try to do any stuff to the NTFS drive from Linux**. Let the Windows do the magic. I was smart enough to remain calm without doing that mistake. Hope this'll help someone else in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't mounted the partitions. You can try to use "DISKS" in ubuntu to look at your ntfs partitions, then just press the image button PLAY to mount the partition you want to interact with.

Comment: thanks. But i have the drive mounted. And i can see few directories. But lot of them are missing. :(